# jQuery div opacity management

Tags: jquery

I am having trouble getting this jQuery to work. I am trying to toggle overlaid divs' visibility. There are five divs and one has the class of 'on' with page load while the rest have the class 'off'. However, when the code executes, the "on" div fades out but the div that should receive the class "on" does not appear. What is the problem?

```
.on{opacity:1;}
.off{opacity:0;)

$('li.tunes').click(
    function() { 
    $('div.on').animate({"opacity":"0"},800).removeClass('on').addClass('off', function()     {
$('div.tunesdiv').removeClass('off').addClass('on')
})
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is pretty off, and you're missing a couple semi-colons. Try something more like:

```
$('li.tunes').click(function(){
  $('div.on').animate({"opacity":"0"},800).removeClass('on').addClass('off', function(){
    $('div.tunesdiv').removeClass('off').addClass('on');
  });
});
```

Also, it's good if you'd provide the source as you have it.

Comment: thanks vap0r, some of the syntax was butchered as a result of me adding it here, but i tried your code and it still didn't work

Answer (score 0):

That second function parameter in addClass seems totally wrong to me, you need to use a handler in the animate function instead.

Here is the code I recommend (.fadeTo() animates the opacity and here is more readable)

try this:

also because fadeTo() will give your element explicit style you need to forget about stylesheets and let your script to rule-out on opacity:

```
$('li.off').fadeTo(1, 0);
$('li.on').fadeTo(1, 1);
$('li.tunes').click(function() { 
    $('div.on').fadeTo(800, 0, function() {
         $(this).removeClass('on').addClass('off');
         $('div.tunesdiv').fadeTo(1, 1).addClass("on").removeClass("off");
       });
});
```

Comment: Thanks Valipour, that works, except that the second iteration, when i click another button, and then re click the same button, will only fade out and nothing will fade back in.

Comment: Alex, can we see the html source please?

Comment: that's because fadeTo gives your element explicit style, see my new comments.

Comment: yeah gimme  a min I'll throw it online

Comment: http://joepolitic.com/zkmpract.html    I'm not sure what you're doing with the <li> items here, they are just buttons in navigation

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery's `fadeIn` ( [ref](http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/) ) and `fadeOut` ( [ref](http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut) )to animate your opacity.
Handing that task to jQuery also helps you with supporting older IE versions that did not suppor the `opacity` CSS attribute.

Comment: Although, if I use this approach, how should I initially load the div elements? Won't css opacity set to 0 initially give me problems?

Comment: you can start with `display:none;`